# Using async/await with Mongoose recent version(6.2.7)

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have the following code to connect to Mongoose DB using Node.js. But I get some kind of warning or refactor notification from VS code to remove *await* from the the part when I try to connect.

Its say that: `await has no effect in this kind of expression`

From the documentation of Mongoose inside *index.d.ts* file;

`export function connect(uri: string, options?: ConnectOptions): Promise<Mongoose>;` returns promise

So I try to do like this:

```
// Provide connection to a new in-memory database server.

const connect = async () => {

// NOTE: before establishing a new connection close previous

await mongoose.disconnect()

mongoServer = await MongoMemoryServer.create()

try {
    const mongoUri = await mongoServer.getUri()
    await mongoose.connect(mongoUri, opts) // No need to use await??
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

Comment: What is a "recent version"? When someone looks at this question in a year, what will be a "recent version" then? Write down the exact version you're using.

Comment: No need, but for this line `const mongoUri = await mongoServer.getUri()`